# What happens when fire hostname "withsometest" on linux server

Tags: linux, shell, hostname

Team,

today i did some mistake on customer production server. Unfortunately i fired hostname 90 on root terminal. then i typed hostname and it returned 90 instead of actual hostname .

It was typo while typing hostname -I. (Checking for IP address )

What happens when you type "hostname 90" on root terminal.?

Thanks.

Comment: That question should be ask to one of our sister site like https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can run `strace hostname 90` to see what is going on, perhaps as a non-root user to avoid breaking the system.  Near the end of the output is this:

```
sethostname("90", 2)                    = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

(Here I didn't run the command as root, hence the `EPERM` error.)

So the `hostname` program calls [`sethostname`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sethostname.2.html) system call with the argument from the command line.  If the system administrator runs this command, it changes the host name to `90`, without further prompts, so a lot of things will go wrong after this point.